# SQL or PHP cascading update and delete

Tags: php, mysql, function, triggers

I am creating a system where you can upload photos to a gallery and you can give that gallery a name and a description and associate it with however many images you want. I am using MySQL and PHP to accomplish this. I have a bit of a dilemma, however and that is that I would like to allow the user to, if they choose to, delete all images accosted with a gallery if they delete the gallery, or set the images to some other default gallery.

the way i have the database set up is with two tables, one is an image table where it has the image name, the description, the actual image name (meaning the .jpeg image), and a gallery id field. the gallery table contains the name, description and it's own id.

I just recently learned a bit about cascading triggers with foreign keys, but i don't understand very well how they work, so I'm not sure if that would be a solution to this. My main goal is to allow the user to delete the gallery and have all of the gallery id's in the image table update, ore have all of those images be deleted. if there is not a way to do that with SQL, how could i do that with PHP? I was trying to figure it out, and came to the conclusion that i may have to use some sort of loop.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you simplify this block of text please?

Comment: I forgot to separate into paragraphs sorry about that. :) I think i have made appropriate adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a person requests to delete one of their galleries and it has id of "34", you could just

```
$gId = 34;
$query = 'DELETE FROM `images` WHERE `gallery_id` = $gId';
$res   = mysql_query($query);

// or assign to new gallery
$gId    = 34;
$newGid = 5;
$query  = 'UPDATE `images` set `gallery_id` = $newGid WHERE `gallery_id` = $gId';
$res    = mysql_query($query);
```

If you are using InnoDB tables in MySQL 5.5, you can see docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) explaining how to  use constraints to achieve the cascading delete or update.